# Neo4j ServiceUnavailable: Failed to establish connection in 5000ms

Tags: neo4j

I have just installed Neo4j on a remote server running Ubuntu 16.04, with Nginx. While I am making my initial tests, I have set up nginx to make the browser visible over the Internet: listening via HTTPS on port 80 to what is happening internally on port 7474:

```
server {
    server_name neo.examplecom;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:7474;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/neo.example.com/fullchain.pem; # mana$
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/neo.example.com/privkey.pem; # ma$
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = neo.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name neo.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I have also used `ufw` to open port `7687` for Bolt.

This is a brand new, empty database, so there is no question of there being high traffic. And yet, each time I attempt to connect, using the default password, I get a red `ServiceUnavailable: Failed to establish connection in 5000ms` error.

I tried deleting the file at `/var/lib/neo4j/data/dbms/auth`, in case that was the issue, but nothing has changed.

Is there a better way of setting up the Neo4j browser, or is there something that I have neglected to do?

Comment: Facing similar issue, Got any solution for this?